# javascript terminate onkeydown eventlistener

Tags: javascript, event-listener, cancellation

I have function that waits for a certain user response (pressing a key).

```
async function alert(){
  let alert_response = await testing_501_alert_response()
}

async function testing_501_alert_response() {
 key_code = [99, 67, 113, 81, 114, 82]
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyHandler);
    function onKeyHandler(e) {
        if (key_code.includes(e.keyCode)) {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyHandler);
            resolve(e.keyCode);
        }
    }
  });
}
```

I would like to be able to abort this "wait" i.e. have a button on the form with onlclick event that will terminate the execution.

Comment: Just add another listener in the promise for click of the button and resolve the promise in there

Comment: @LucaKiebel Can you show an example. I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @goryef ... there is nothing asynchronous in the above provided example code which would justify writing a `Promise` and then in addition being forced to use *`async` ... `await`* syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of implementing a removeEventListener on button click:

```js
function trigger() {
  key_code = [99, 67, 113, 81, 114, 82] // c
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyHandler);
}

function cancel() {
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyHandler);
}

function onKeyHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode)
  if (key_code.includes(e.keyCode)) {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyHandler);
    
    // do whatever you want with this handler here
  }
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 85%; top: auto; }
```

```html
<button onclick="trigger()">trigger</button>
<button onclick="cancel()">cancel</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9b2xf1no/2/